# Implementing infinite scroll with RTK query

Tags: rtk-query

I'm trying to implement an infinite scroll based on the work of [HassanHeydariNasab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9408431/hassanheydarinasab?tab=profile) (great work though) using RTK query but I'm stuck on a few points. I'm not very familiar to RTK query.

Source code is here => https://github.com/HassanHeydariNasab/infinite-scrolling-rtk

Here is an example of the data I receive from the API => http://83.171.249.198/sorare/player/4591/cards?l=20&o=0

So I first made two API endpoints like this with RTK Query :

```
getPlayerCards: builder.query({
  async queryFn(arg, queryApi, extraOptions, fetchWithBQ) {
    const { id, limit, offset } = arg;
    const response = await fetchWithBQ(
      `player/${id}/cards?l=${limit}&o=${offset}`
    );
    let playerCards = [];
    for (let i = offset; i < offset + limit; i++) {
      playerCards.push(response.data.data.cards[i]);
    }
    
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve({
          data: {
            total: 100,
            playerCards,
          },
        });
      }, 1000);
    });
  },
}),
getAllCards: builder.query({
  queryFn: (_, { getState }) => {
    const state = getState();
    let cards = [];
    for (let offset = 0; offset < 100; offset += 20) {
      const { data } = apiRequests.endpoints.getPlayerCards.select({
        offset,
        limit: 20
      })(state);
      if (data && data.playerCards) {
        cards.push(...data?.playerCards);
      }
    }
    return Promise.resolve({ data: { total: 100, playerCards: cards} });
  }
}),
```

Then, in my component I use the queries like this :

```
// ** Api queries
import {
  useGetPlayerCardsQuery,
  useGetAllCardsQuery,
} from '../../../lib/queries/apiQueries';

const LIMIT = 20;

const PlayerCards = ({ playerId }) => {
const [cards, setCards] = useState([]);
const [offset, setOffset] = useState(0);
const { data, isFetching, originalArgs } = useGetPlayerCardsQuery({
  id: playerId,
  offset,
  limit: LIMIT,
});

const { data: allCards, refetch: refetchAllCards } = useGetAllCardsQuery();
useEffect(() => {
console.log({ allCards });
}, [allCards]);

useEffect(() => {
  if (data && originalArgs) {
    if (cards.length !== data.total) {
    setCards(new Array(data.total));
  }
  setCards((currentCards) => {
    currentCards.splice(
      originalArgs.offset,
      originalArgs.limit,
      ...data.playerCards
    );
    return currentCards;
  });
  refetchAllCards();
 }
}, [data]);

const onEndReached = () => {
  if (!isFetching && data && offset + LIMIT <= data.total) {
  setOffset((currentOffset) => (currentOffset += LIMIT));
  }
};

const onScroll = (event) => {
  const { scrollTop, scrollHeight, offsetHeight } = event.target;
  if (scrollTop + offsetHeight > scrollHeight * 0.8) {
  onEndReached();
  }
};

return (
  <div>
    <div id={'container'} onScroll={onScroll}>
      <Row className="row-cols-1 row-cols-sm-2 row-cols-md-3 row-cols-lg-4 row-cols-xl-5">
      {cards
        .filter((i) => {
          return i !== undefined;
        })
        .map((card, index) => (
          <Col key={index}>
            <PlayerCard key={card.id} card={card} />
          </Col>
        ))}
      </Row>
      {isFetching && <Spinner />}
    </div>
  </div>
  );
};
export default PlayerCards;
```

First render is ok and I see my 20 first cards but when I scroll, parameters are well send to the `getPlayerCards` query and when I check the response I can see the next batch of cards with limit and offset but the returned Promise data is undefined.

[image]

I think the problem comes from the push in my for loop but I can't figure out what's wrong. Maybe I need to make an object based on my response and then push it in my playerCards Array...

When I use something like `playerCards.push({id: i.toString(), name: 'card ${i}'});` everything works fine but in my case I need to push the whole array I receive.

Secondly the `useGetAllCardsQuery` never returns results so I'm never able to refetch all cards.

Any adice would be appreciated. Hassan if you hear me :)

Thanks.